Certbot not creating .wellknown/acme-challenge file
I'm trying to setup Let's Encrypt certbot on a docker container hosted on nginx.
Since nginx is just a proxy-pass to a docker container, I'm forwarding requests to .well-known to the disk
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

and calling it like this
certbot --nginx --webroot-path /var/www/certbot -d dev.mydomain.com

It fails the validation:

Invalid response from http://dev.satrimono.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/eSVrXetc

Both nginx root and certbot consider /var/www/certbot as the root folder and should create .well-known folder inside of it.
Adding /var/www/certbot/.well-known/acme-challenge/file1.txt gets served properly.
Why is certbot not creating the needed file?
According to this command, nothing gets created there.
watch -n 0.5 ls -a /var/www/certbot


Consider asking in the lets encrypt forum; they solved my certbot problem.

Good idea. Moving the discussion here https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certbot-not-creating-wellknown-acme-challenge-file/217561
